# Finding the length of a curve of intersection between a parabolic cylinder and a surface.

Tags: analytic-geometry, curves, parametrization, arc-length

If $A$ is the curve of intersection of the parabolic cylinder $x^2 = 2y$ and the
surface $3z = xy$, then what is the length of $A$ from the origin to the point (6, 18, 36)?

**What I have done so far:**

I know to parametrise the cylinder to get $x$ and $y$ in terms of $sin$ and $cos$ however I am unsure of how to do this.

Comment: The given point of intersection $(3,6,12)$ does not lie on _either_ surface.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel my bad I have corrected the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^2=2y\implies y=x^2/2$$
$$3z=xy=x^3/2$$
Let $x=t$. Then $A$ from the origin to $(6,18,36)$ is parametrised as
$$(t,t^2/2,t^3/6)\qquad t\in[0,6]$$
The arc length is
$$\int_0^6\sqrt{1^2+t^2+(t^2/2)^2}\,dt=\frac12\int_0^6\sqrt{t^4+4t^2+4}\,dt$$
$$=\frac12\int_0^6(t^2+2)\,dt=\frac12\left[\frac13t^3+2t\right]_0^6=42$$

Comment: I have a few questions: how do you get that $t\in[0,6]$? Do you just take the $x$ points from the point in question and the origin? Also to calculate the arc length where has the expression that is in the integral come from? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @butterchi (1) Yes I just took the $x$-coordinates and subbed in (that was how I spotted the original endpoint's error). (2) The arc length of a parametric curve $(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ over $[a,b]$ is $\int_a^b\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2+z'(t)^2}\,dt$. This follows from the Pythagorean theorem applied to an infinitesimal stretch of the curve.